# Loading a Random Caption from a text file using Javascript and Displaying via HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load a random caption every time my page is loaded. I have a separate text file and contained on each line is a string. I am new to both html and Javascript, as you will see.

HTML:

```
<div class="centerpiece">
                <h1>DEL NORTE BANQUEST</h1>
                <p class="caption"><script src = "js/caption.js"></script><script>getCaption();</script></p>
                <a class="btn" id="browse-videos-button" href="#video-list">Browse Videos<br><img src="img/arrow-down.svg"style="width:15px;height:15px;"></a>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getCaption()
{
  var txtFile = "text/captions.txt"
  var file = new File(txtFile);
  file.open("r"); // open file with read access
  var str = "";
  var numLines = 0; //to get the range of lines in the file
  while (!file.eof)
  {
      // read each line of text
      numLines += 1;
  }
  file.close();
  file.open("r");
  var selectLine = Math.getRandomInt(0,numLines);//get the correct line number
  var currentLine = 0;
  while(selectLine != currentLine)
  {
    currentLine += 1;
  }
  if(selectLine = currentLine)
  {
    str = file.readln();
  }
  file.close();
  return str;
}
```

Text in Source File:

```
We talked yesterday
Freshman boys!
5/10
I'm having a heart attack *pounds chest super hard
```

The site is for my highschool cross country team in case the text file was confusing.

I am unfamiliar with most syntax and was unable to see if by iterating through the file with a loop if i needed to reset somehow which is why I opened and closed the file twice. Here is a jsfiddle of the specific caption I am trying to change and what my function is in Javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/7cre9qqj/

If you need more code to work with please let me know and any critiques you may have please dont hold back if it looks like a mess, I am trying to learn after all! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The [`File` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) allows access to the file system on the *client* side, so it's not really suited to what you want to do. It's also only allowed to be used in very specific circumstances.

A simple solution is to just run an AJAX request to populate your quote. The AJAX call can read the file on your server, then it's simple to split the contents of the file by line, and pick a random line to display. Since you're open to jQuery, the code is pretty simple:

```
$.get("text/captions.txt")).then(function(data) {
  var lines = data.split('\n');
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
  $("#quote").html(lines[index]);
});
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates it in full; every time it runs it will load a random quote: https://jsfiddle.net/s1w8x4ff/

Comment: Is there a vanilla javascript solution?